# where to find the definition of a external variable?

Tags: c++

Where can I find the definition of end_of_list? I searched the whole project from eclipse, but can't find the definition. But when put end_of_list as an expression when debug, I can see it's value, just don't where from which file to find it.

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <drizzled/memory/sql_alloc.h>
#include <drizzled/visibility.h>

namespace drizzled {
    ....    
#define DRIZZLED_API __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
extern DRIZZLED_API list_node end_of_list;  // where to find **end_of_list**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see two immediate possibilities.

1. The Eclipse search functionality is not up to scratch, either because it's buggy (unlikely) or the actual definition of that item is held somewhere outside its scope (say, for example, you're including a header that isn't in the project).
2. The actual definition is not *in* a source file at all but possibly in an object file or library, in which case you probably *shouldn't* be worried about the definition - it's "hidden" for reasons of encapsulation.

Granted, these are guesses, but it's the best I can do with the information given, and I'd at least like to *think* that they're educated guesses :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using "extern" to declare it in your code, then it was defined in another source file that probably came compiled in the library you're using. See:

http://drizzle.org/lcov/drizzled/sql_list.cc.gcov.html

Comment: Thanks Fabio, but it only said:  list_node end_of_list;  it has no value. What's the value for it?

Comment: It looks like the object address is used as a "magic pointer" to mark the last element in linked lists, so its value is not really important. Anyway, notice that it has a default constructor that initializes info=0;next=this

Comment: Also check out this comment found in sql_list.h: "All list ends with a pointer to the 'end_of_list' element, which data pointer is a null pointer and the next pointer points to itself. This makes it very fast to traverse lists as we don't have to test for a specialend condition for list that can't contain a null pointer."